# SplitViewContoller is nil when perform modal segue?

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I have an app using SplitViewController as root view. But I want a login View before go to main. My solution is hide master view at login view. After check user info, I perform a modal segue (I use storyboard with iOS 5.0). I also update delegate to detail view like this post:
[iOS - UISplitViewController with storyboard - multiple master views and multiple detail views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538231/ios-uisplitviewcontroller-with-storyboard-multiple-master-views-and-multiple):

But in detail view, the splitViewController is still nil ??? I log by using description and see that the splitViewController.delegate in prepareForSegue (at LoginView.m)is the same with description of DetaiView in ViewDidload (at DetailView.m). And I also sure that splitViewController is not nil in prepareForSegue. So, what wrong with that?? Why the splitViewController is nil in detailView ? (my masterview is nil in detailView too).

Please help me to fix that problem, thank you very much