# iOS - UISplitViewController in storyboard - multiple master views and multiple detail views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I am developing a new iPad application . I end up with multiple master as well as multiple detail.

I searched the stackoverflow and found the same article : [iOS - UISplitViewController with storyboard - multiple master views and multiple detail views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538231/ios-uisplitviewcontroller-with-storyboard-multiple-master-views-and-multiple)

Since I am a new user, I can not comment on the same article.

My question is where should I put the `UISplitViewController` in storyboard?

As per the above article , "(1)Navigation Controller -> (2) table view of 6 menu options -> (3) Each cell in the table pushes a different table view controller onto the navigation stack."

should I put split view controller here before (3) or it will go somewhere else?

I am new to ios development, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link:

[uisplitviewcontroller](http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/)

From my experience, you should place split view controller at first place, as master detail are going to embedded in `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I will implement it and let you know how does it go.